# base64 encoded image isn't being sent by POST

Tags: php, javascript, base64

I have a couple of image drop places made with `html5`. When the image is parsed and converted to data (and encoded in `base64`), I grab that data and send via post to a php file.

On localhost, that `base64` string is received perfectly in the php file. However, when I move to a server, both image preprocessing and `base64` sending to the server work (I read the headers), but when in the php file, that `base64` string is no longer there. Is there anything I am missing?

Some extra information:

- I don't url encode the string, because without doing so it worked locally, and doing that the server still doesn't get the `base64` data.
- I haven't topped the `post_max_size` (`8M` in my case, yet the `base64` string plus the other data weights about `50kb`)

#### Breaking news

I tried to upload 600kb of data. Now the server prompts this:

```
<html><head>
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />/altmail/admin/calls/ajax.previewnewsletter.php<br />
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.
</body></html>
```

Again, `post_max_size` is big enough.

#### Breaking news 2

After uploading the opposite, a 38x38, 220bytes picture, it uploaded correctly.

Comment: Have tried using a packet sniffer like Fiddler to inspect the request to the server and it's response back?

Comment: No, I haven't. I thought web dev console would suffice in this kind of requests.

Comment: I though the console just showed the headers, could be wrong though.

Comment: the headers, plus the response (and a preview, but that doesn't matter). When I `var_dump($_POST)`, it shows up each variable I uploaded, except the encoded data. It's kind of disturbing

Comment: `413 Request Entity Too Large` This problem usually occurs because of some **Header** sent, You are sending via Ajax? Put the Javascript code with your question please.

Comment: php's upload limit may be high enough, but apache has its own `LimitRequestBody` as well. php cannot override that.

Comment: Is there any way to check so from php?

Comment: no. you'll have to rummage around in the httpd.conf

Comment: or try overriding it with a .htaccess in the same dir as your upload script

Comment: It looks like a shared server, so no apache rummage. And an .htaccess with LimitRequestBody 0 didn't do the trick.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento yes, it is ajax, but the ajax code is not tricky. The only thing I do is to append a string in front of the base64 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Apache Request size limits:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#LimitRequestFieldSize

There is a limit in the size of everything where it comes to HTTP, so if something works here and not there, increase the sizes there. ;)

Comment: After a short talk with the hosting guys, they modified `LimitRequestFieldSize` and it magically worked! This may come to some security flaws, but neither the client nor the hosters seem to worry about that. Thanks, here comes a +1 too

Answer (score 0):

You're saving the **base64** data into a file? If so maybe the folder is not marked for **"WRITE"**, check that.

You are using `$_POST` or is using global variables in Localhost.
If you are using **Global** change to `$_POST`.

If you are using RAW, use the variable like this:
`$_GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']`

Comment: I can't even get the base64 string from $_POST. I am planning on store into a db until a specific time. The problem is that that data never comes to the server

Comment: Try using the console of `Google Chrome`/`Safari`/`Firebug`, check the Network tab and see how the request comes.
You are using Ajax?

Comment: see the comments below the question and the edit. I am already using such console.

Comment: Put an example online then, so easy to identify the problem.